# Hp-ux comamnd or script to send Magic Packet to do Wake On Lan (WOL)

Tags: hp-ux, wake-on-lan

Is there any script or utility to send Magic Packet to do Wake On Lan (WOL) on hp-ux machine. I am finding many tools for windows. following are such tools.

http://www.matcode.com/wol.htm (windows console based)

http://www.depicus.com/wake-on-lan/wake-on-lan-gui.aspx (windows GUI based)

If you know the kind of tool for HP-UX, please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

Sending WoL packet is quite easy when you understand that it can contain the magic sequence anywhere. So just produce any packet (TCP/HTTP or UDP) which will contain it. Usually it is done by UDP on some port which is not blocked. You can find example scripts in many languages...

For example my PHP script (little overkill as it can manage whole LAN of computers) http://www.marki-online.net/WoL/

Or for example this small Perl script (HP-UX should have perl already available) - http://www.han.de/~gero/netboot/archive/msg02524.html